# ffmpeg adds unneeded zero samples at beginning of resulting m4a file

Tags: ffmpeg

Input file original.wav

```
ffmpeg -i original.wav
...
  Duration: 00:03:36.93, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
```

Convert wav to m4a with fdk-aac encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i original.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 5 ffmpeg.m4a
```

Check duration of resulting m4a:

```
ffmpeg -i ffmpeg.m4a
...
  Duration: 00:03:36.98, start: 0.046440, bitrate: 240 kb/s
```

So, ffmpeg adds ~2000 zero samples at beginning of resulting file. How to disable this?

[image: Waveforms]

I try few different codecs and all work fine, problem only with fdk-aac.

- ffmpeg versions: 2.2.10 and 2.4.3
- fdk-aac version: 0.1.1 and 0.1.3

UPD1: I try fdkaac and vlc (it also use fdk-aac library). Both produce correct file (no zero samples at begin). So problem only with ffmpeg+fdk.

Comment: Is `ffmpeg` adding the padding, or is it the external encoding library? Does it also occur if you use [`fdkaac`](https://github.com/nu774/fdkaac)? It's a command line encoder frontend for libfdk-aac.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this also with libfdk_aac and x264 and am not sure what causes it but I have had success using the `itsoffset` flag like this:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 0.046440 -i original.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 5 ffmpeg.m4a
```